# Why did Brihaspati establish Charvaka or materialistic philosophical Sect?

Tags: philosophy, atheism, brihaspati, charvaka

Brihaspati is DevaGuru, the spiritual Guru of the Gods. More so, He is the planet of Spirituality​. Brihaspati is the God of all knowledge and intellect. So Brihaspati could bring the philosophical or logical thinking sect. But Baarhaspatya thoughts just disregard Spirituality​. How is this possible?

Comment: It is generally accepted that there are two brhaspatis. One is the deva guru and the other is an ordinary mortal who propounded the lokayata theory. This second "brihaspati" is also considered a legend and not an actual person. Some people may have attributed the epithet to this theorist metaphorically.

Comment: @moonstar2001 It is only accepted. What is the truth. Why is there a lot of ambiguity in our Hinduism.

Comment: The truth is that devaguru would not propound carvakism. It only seems ambiguous. And it is a not-so-subtle hint for us to dig deeper.

Comment: @moonstar2001 `It is generally accepted that there are two brhaspatis.` Any sources for this?

Comment: Brihaspati, vashishta, kashyapa etc. are often used as surnames i.e. it can also mean person belonging to that gotra, so not every scripture whose author is brihaspati is the primal brihaspati

Answer (score 8):

**Brihaspati created the Charvaka system to deceive the Asuras.**. [Here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe15/sbe15118.htm) is what the seventh Prapathaka of the Maitrayaniya Upanishads says:

> 9. Brihaspati, having become Sukra, brought forth that false knowledge for the safety of Indra and for the destruction of the Asuras. By it they show that good is evil, and that evil is good. They say that we ought to ponder on the (new) law, which upsets the Veda and the other sacred books. Therefore let no one ponder on that false knowledge: it is wrong, it is, as it were, barren. Its reward lasts only as long as the pleasure lasts, as with one who has fallen from his caste. Let that false science not be attempted, for thus it is said: 
>    (1) Widely opposed and divergent are these two, the one known as false knowledge, the other as knowledge. I (Yama) believe Nakiketas to be possessed by a desire of knowledge; even many pleasures do not move thee. 
>    (2) He who knows at the same time both the imperfect (sacrifice, &c.) and the perfect knowledge (of the Self), he crosses death by means of the imperfect, and obtains immortality by means of the perfect knowledge. 
>    (3) Those who are wrapped up in the midst of imperfect knowledge, fancying themselves alone wise and learned, they wander about floundering and deceived, like the blind led by the blind.

[This excerpt](http://gdurl.com/P8Ne) from the Padma Purana provides more detail, in the course of a dialogue between Shiva and Parvati:

> In the age of Swayambhuva (Manu) in olden times there were great demons like Namuchi, who were very powerful, very valorous, very strong and great heroes.  All of them were devoted to Vishnu, were pure, and free from all sins.  They followed the practices (laid down) in the triad of the Vedas.  All gods, being frustrated, led by Indra, and overcome by fear, approached Vishnu and sought his shelter....  [Vishnu told Shiva:] "There will be Brahmanas and great sages who have given themselves away to me.  Approaching them through devotion for me, tell the vicious ones: Kanada, Gautama, Shakti, Upamanyu, Jaimini, Kapila, Durvasa, Mrikandu, **Brihaspati**, Bhargava and Jamadagnya[.] ... By your power increased in viciousness infused into them they will be vicious in a moment.  There is no doubt about it.... Taking to their doctrine all the ancient demons will be averse to me in a moment." ... O sinless one, having entered through my power, Gautama and other Brahmanas I proclaimed the texts outside the Vedic fold.  Resorting to this doctrine, all the wicked demons became averse to the lord (i.e. Vishnu), and were enveloped in viciousness.... On receiving from me grants of boons, they were haughty with pride of power.  They were very much attached to objects of senses, and were full of lust and anger.  They, void of goodness and powerless, were then defeated by the hosts of gods....
>
> I shall tell you the various texts in a sequence. By merely remembering them even the wise ones would be deluded.  First I myself proclaimed the Shaiva, Pashupata, etc.  Hear about the ones proclaimed by the Brahmanas into whom my power had entered after that: Kanada proclaimed the great Vaisheshika text. Similarly Gautama (proclaimed the doctrine of) Nyaya, and Kapila proclaimed Samkhya. **Dhishana (Brihaspati) in the same way (proclaimed)the much censured Charvaka.** Vishnu of the form of Buddha proclaimed the false Buddhist doctrine and those of the naked and wearing dark blue garments for the destruction of demons. The doctrine of Maya is a wicked doctrine and said to be pseudo-Buddhist.  I myself, in the form of a Brahmana proclaimed it in Kali (age).

Comment: @Rohit, yeah, Devas are the wicked people and Asuras are the benevolent ones. That must be why God helps Devas vanquish Asuras.

Comment: @Rohit., yeah there is nobody more wicked than Gods, idk why anybody worships them

Comment: This excerpt which lists various heretical teachings and further on divides puranas and smritis as sattvic vs rajasic vs tamasic is present in all versions of padma purana or only in some versions?

Comment: @Aks All versions.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, No philosophy is Man created;Every philosophy is already inherently present in the nature. It just manifests according to the demand. **All philosophies are describing the role of consciousness only.** From Prtyabhijnahridyam of the acharya Kshemraja

> The positions of the various systems of
>   philosophy are only various roles of that (Consciousness
>   or Self). Sutra-7

It means every philosophy manifests according to the demand. No philosophy dies nor any philosophy ever born, just appears & disappears according to demand. Demand here means consciousness. Existence of people with particular consciousness is demand in nature actually by which some particular philosophy manifest. Now, to manifest it initially a propagator is needed who is fit to propagate. Brihaspati propagated not because he actually believes the philosophy but because of demand as people with such consciousness were prevailing in that time. So philosophies are just the roles of consciousness.

From the same Shastra,
**The positions of the various systems of philosophy are, so to
speak, roles assumed by the Self**.

1. The Carvakas, for instance, maintain that the Self is
   identical with the BODY characterised by consciousness.
2. The followers of Nyaya practically consider BUDDHI to
   be the Self in the worldly condition. After liberation, they
   consider Self as identical with the void.
3. The Mimamsakas also practically consider Buddhi to
   be the Self inasmuch as they believe the I-CONSCIOUSNESS to be
   the Self.
4. The Buddhists also consider only the functions of BUDDHI
   as the Self.
5. Some Vedantins regard PRANA as the Self.
6. Some of the Vedantins and the Madhyamikas regard
   'NON-BEING' as the fundamental principle.
7. The followers of Pancaratra believe Vasudeva to be the
   highest cause.
8. The followers of Sankhya practically accept the position
   of the Vijnanakalas.
9. Some Vedantins accept ISVARA as the highest principle.
10. The Grammarians consider PASYANTI or SADASIVA to be
    the highest reality.
11. The Tantrikas consider the ATMAN as transcending the
    universe to be the highest principle.
12. The Kaulas consider the UNIVERSE as the Atman principle.
13. The followers of Trika philosophy maintain that the
    ATMAN is both immanent and transcendent.

Comment: Where in the Pratyabhijna Hridayam is that list of 1 to 13?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan You may find in Jaidev SIngh's translation in summary.

Comment: If every idea is philosophy then what is the truth. Maybe the concept of Brahma is also a mere thought, where in reality, the material world, as we call it, is the real world.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Read the phrase in the block `roles of consciousness` suggest there is consciousness or self otherwise whose roles there would have been? So the concept of Brahman/Consciousness is not a thought. Moreover, ultimate reality can't be played with the words; it transcends everything as it is beyond comprehension.