# Is it valid to quote half-lines of ślokas?

Tags: scripture, dharma, dharma-shastras, shloka, reference-request

While reading *nibandha*s like *Nirṇayasindhu* & *Smṛtitattva*, it is found that the authors often quoted half-verses instead of the entire verse. For example, *Kamalākara Bhaṭṭa* quotes 'शरत्काले महापूजा क्रियते या च वार्षिकी।' only, omitting the next part (तस्यां ममैतन्माहात्म्यं श्रुत्वा भक्तिसमन्वितः॥) while writing about *Navarāṭri*. However this tactic can be easily abused as shown below in the next example

> तच्छ्रुत्वा वचनं काव्यो जगाम त्वरितस्ततः ।
> अपश्यद्दानवानां च पार्श्वे वाचस्पतिं तदा ॥
> छद्मरूपधरं सौम्यं बोधयन्तं छलेन तान् ।
> जैनं धर्मं कृतं स्वेन यज्ञनिन्दापरं तथा ॥
> भो देवरिपवः सत्यं ब्रवीमि भवतां हितम् ।
> अहिंसा परमो धर्मोऽहन्तव्या ह्याततायिनः ॥
> द्विजैर्भोगरतैर्वेदे दर्शितं हिंसनं पशोः ।
> जिह्वास्वादपरैः काममहिंसैव परा मता ॥
> एवंविधानि वाक्यानि वेदशास्त्रपराणि च ।
> ब्रुवाणं गुरुमाकर्ण्य विस्मितोऽसौ भृगोः सुतः ॥
> चिन्तयामास मनसा मम द्वेष्यो गुरुः किल ।
> वञ्चिताः किल धूर्तेन याज्या मे नात्र संशयः ॥
> धिग्लोभं पापबीजं वै नरकद्वारमूर्जितम् ।
> गुरुरप्यनृतं ब्रूते प्रेरितो येन पाप्मना ॥
> प्रमाणं वचनं यस्य सोऽपि पाखण्डधारकः ।
> गुरुः सुराणां सर्वेषां धर्मशास्त्रप्रवर्तकः ॥
>
> On hearing those words, *Kāvya* i.e *Śukra* quickly returned back & saw the Master of Speech i.e *Bṛhaspati* there by the side of the *Dānava*s. In disguise (of *Śukra*), he was explaining to them the Jaina doctrines created by him, criticising the performance of *yajña* & other activities. On hearing lines alien to the *Veda*s & scriptures spoken by the *Guru* like, "Hear, O enemies of the *Deva*s, the truth spoken by me for your welfare. Non-violence is the greatest virtue, even assassins shouldn't be killed. Injunctions for violence against animals are found in the *Veda* because the *brāhmaṇa*s are addicted to sensual pleasures & want to satisfy the cravings of their tongues (implying that the *Veda*s aren't *apauraṣeya* but composed by *brāhmaṇa*s), non-violence is the supreme virtue." the son of *Bhṛgu* was astonished. He thought to himself, "Surely this is *Guru*, my enemy. Undoubtedly, my *yajamāna*s have been deceived by this cheat. Fie to greed, the seed of sin, the excellent gateway to hell, under whose influence even this *Guru* of sinful mind is speaking lies. He whose very statements are considered as authority, the promulgator of all religious texts, even that *guru* of the *Sura*s have become the bearer of heresy." [*Devībhāgavatapurāna Purāṇa*:4:13:53-60]

So is there scriptural reference in support of glorifying even a half-verse ?

Comment: does this ans. your question  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19862/why-did-brihaspati-establish-charvaka-or-materialistic-philosophical-sect

Comment: No. I want to know whether a half-verse has as power as a complete verse.

Comment: It's nothing to do with power. It just saves space, some wordings of the śloka easily point out the reference, those interested may check the ślokas in detail. I have seen this in commentaries on smṛtis, etc. too, usually only that much is quoted, as is needed by the commentator to support/argue, or a part is quoted, leaving the reader to check the rest of it in the quoted reference.